# Numpy view contiguous part of non-contiguous array as dtype of bigger size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-layout

I was trying to generate an array of trigrams (i.e. continuous-three-letter combinations) from a super long char array:

```
# data is actually load from a source file
a = np.random.randint(0, 256, 2**28, 'B').view('c')
```

Since making copy is not efficient (and it creates problems like cache miss), I directly generated the trigram using stride tricks:

```
tri = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (len(a) - 2, 3), a.strides * 2)
```

This generates a trigram list with shape `(2**28 - 2, 3)` where each row is a trigram. Now I want to convert the trigram to a list of string (i.e. `S3`) so that numpy displays it more "reasonably" (instead of individual chars).

```
tri = tri.view('S3')
```

It gives the exception:

```
ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the array must be C-contiguous
```

I understand generally data should be contiguous in order to create a meaningful view, but this data is contiguous at "where it should be": each three elements are contiguous.

So I'm wondering **how to `view` contiguous part in non-contiguous `np.ndarray` as dtype of bigger size**? A more "standard" way would be better, while hackish ways are also welcome. It seems that I can set `shape` and `stride` freely with `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, but I can't force the `dtype` to be something, which is the problem here.

**EDIT**

Non-contiguous array can be made by simple slicing. For example:

```
np.empty((8, 4), 'uint32')[:, :2].view('uint64')
```

will throw the same exception above (while from a memory point of view I should be able to do this). This case is much more common than my example above.

Comment: What about `np.ascontiguousarray(tri).view('S3')` ?

Comment: @AndyK I believe OP wants to avoid the copy that this forces.

Comment: The databuffer for any array is contiguous - one long low level array of bytes.  But a view of that buffer might not be 'C' contiguous.  In the `[:,:2]` case there are 2 elements, then a gap, 2 more elements, etc.  Look at the `flags`.  Evidently `view` isn't going the extra step of verifying that the 8 bytes it needs for each `uint64` are contiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to a contiguous array from which your non-contiguous one is derived, it should typically be possible to work around this limitation.

For example your trigrams can be obtained like so:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 256, 2**28, 'B').view('c')
>>> a
array([b')', b'\xf2', b'\xf7', ..., b'\xf4', b'\xf1', b'z'], dtype='|S1')
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[:0].view('S3'), ((2**28)-2,), (1,))
array([b')\xf2\xf7', b'\xf2\xf7\x14', b'\xf7\x14\x1b', ...,
       b'\xc9\x14\xf4', b'\x14\xf4\xf1', b'\xf4\xf1z'], dtype='|S3')
```

In fact, this example demonstrates that all we need is a contiguous "stub" at the memory buffer's base for view casting, since afterwards, because `as_strided` does not do many checks we are essentially free to do whatever we like.

It seems we can always get such a stub by slicing to a size 0 array. For your second example:

```
>>> X = np.empty((8, 4), 'uint32')[:, :2]
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X[:0].view(np.uint64), (8, 1), X.strides)
array([[140133325248280],
       [             32],
       [       32083728],
       [       31978800],
       [              0],
       [       29686448],
       [             32],
       [       32362720]], dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: That's interesting, although quite difficult to understand why it works. +1

Comment: `view`ing a size-zero array is interesting! I was thinking about somehow create a correct-dtype array (like size-one array from viewing bytes), but size-zero view is definitely more useful!

Comment: As part of a PR to add some string indexing to numpy, I came up with basically this method. One interesting side effect is that you can always get a contiguous buffer with enough motivation. See here for an example: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694

Comment: Once #20722 passes, this will no longer be necessary, but what a neat hack.

Answer (score 2):

As of numpy 1.23.0, you will be able to do exactly what you want without jumping through extra hoops. I've added [PR#20722](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722) to numpy to address pretty much this exact issue. The idea is that if your new dtype is smaller than the current, you can clearly expand a unit or contiguous axis without any problems. If the new dtype is larger, you can shrink a contiguous axis.

With the update, your code runs out of the box:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 256, 2**28, 'B').view('c')
>>> a
array([b'\x19', b'\xf9', b'\r', ..., b'\xc3', b'\xa3', b'{'], dtype='|S1')
>>> tri = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (len(a)-2,3), a.strides*2)
>>> tri.view('S3')
array([[b'\x9dB\xeb'],
       [b'B\xebU'],
       [b'\xebU\xa4'],
       ...,
       [b'-\xcbM'],
       [b'\xcbM\x97'],
       [b'M\x97o']], dtype='|S3')
```

The array has to have a unit dimension or be contiguous in the last axis, which is true in your case.

---

I've also added [PR#20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694) to introduce slicing to the [`np.char`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html) module. If that PR gets accepted as-is, you will be able to do:

```
>>> np.char.slice_(a.view(f'U{len(a)}'), step=1, chunksize=3)
```